# Fingerprinting map with RSSI scanner using C#

Tags: c#, wifi, rssi, fingerprinting

I've recently been trying to make a Wifi scanner which scans all Wifi AP's in order to retrieve their RSSI values. The language I've been using is C# and I use the Native Wifi API for getting the values.
Because of stackoverflow I've been able to get this working.

**The problem**: I'm trying to scan all AP's using a timer (once every second). However, when I'm moving to another point, the only RSSI changing is the one that I'm connected with. All the other values remain the same. Is there any way I can have the other RSSI values change every second?

Thanks in advance, 
Kurt

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using NativeWifi;

namespace FormFingerPrint
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    static int timerCount = 1;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static String GetTimestamp(DateTime value)
    {
        return value.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    }

    public void AddItemToList(int id, string wind, string SSID, string BSSID, string rssi, string x, string y, string timeStamp){
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(id.ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(wind);
        item.SubItems.Add(SSID);
        item.SubItems.Add(BSSID);
        item.SubItems.Add(rssi);
        item.SubItems.Add(x.ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(y.ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(timeStamp);
        lstvFingerPrint.Items.Add(item);
    }

    public bool checkInput()
    {
        return (cboWindrichting.SelectedItem != null && txtX.Text != "" && txtY.Text != "");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(ScanWifi);
        myTimer.Interval = 500;
        myTimer.Start();

    }

    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstvFingerPrint.Items.Clear();
    }


    private void ScanWifi(Object myObject,EventArgs myEventArgs){


        if (checkInput() && timerCount <=1000)
        {
            using (WlanClient client = new WlanClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    lstvFingerPrint.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces)
                    {

                        Wlan.WlanBssEntry[] wlanBssEntries = wlanIface.GetNetworkBssList();



                        foreach (Wlan.WlanBssEntry network in wlanBssEntries)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(network.rssi);
                            int id = 1;
                            string SSID = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(network.dot11Ssid.SSID).ToString();
                            string rss = network.rssi.ToString();
                            string windrichting = cboWindrichting.SelectedItem.ToString();
                            //MessageBox.Show(rss.ToString());
                            string x = txtX.Text.ToString();
                            string y = txtY.Text.ToString();
                            byte[] macAddr = network.dot11Bssid;
                            //Indien frequentie nodig zou zijn
                            //string freq = network.chCenterFrequency.ToString();
                            string tMac = "";

                            for (int i = 0; i < macAddr.Length; i++)
                            {
                                tMac += macAddr[i].ToString("x2").PadLeft(2, '0').ToUpper();
                            }

                            string timeStamp = GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now);
                            if (!(SSID.Contains("TELENETHOMESPOT")))
                            {
                                AddItemToList(id, windrichting, SSID, tMac, rss, x, y, timeStamp);
                                id++;
                            }
                        }
                        //Console.ReadLine();
                        timerCount++;
                    }

                }   
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            myTimer.Stop();
            timerCount = 1;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please show us some code how you retrieve and print the values.

Comment: Code is added to question Icewind. (I'm a beginning programmer so please be kind ;) )